# Cannot read property 'params' of undefined - cannot get product id

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to get product id from url using `match.params.id` to pass into api call but its giving error, match returns undefined is use match?.params?.id

```
Cannot read property 'params' of undefined
```

App.js

```
  <Router>
    <Switch>
       <Route path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL +"/images/upload/:id"}>
          <UploadImages />
       </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
```

Redirect:

```
 //params.id from material-ui datagrid table
  <LinkContainer to={`/admin-panel/home/images/upload/${params.id}`}> 
    <button className="btn btn-primary mr-2">Set Images</button>
  </LinkContainer>
```

```
    const columns = [
    { field: '_id', headerName: 'ID', width: 250 },
    { field: 'name', headerName: 'Product Name', width: 300 },
    { field: 'price', headerName: 'Price', width: 130 },
    { field: 'countInStock', headerName: 'Count In Stock', width: 230 },
    { field: 'createdAt', headerName: 'Date Created', width: 230 },
    { 
        field: 'action', 
        headerName: 'Action', 
        width: 350,
        renderCell: (params)=>{
            return (
                <div>
                    <LinkContainer to={`/admin-panel/home/product/${params.id}/edit`}>
                        <button className="btn btn-info mr-2">Edit</button>
                    </LinkContainer>
                    <LinkContainer to={`/images/upload/${params.id}`}>
                        <button className="btn btn-primary mr-2">Set Images</button>
                    </LinkContainer>
                    <Button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={()=>deleteHandler(params.id)} ><Delete /></Button>
                </div>
            )
        }
    },
];
return (
    <div className="productList" style={{height:600}} >

     

        {loading ? (<Loader />) : error ? (<Message variant="danger" >{error}</Message>):(
            <DataGrid
            rows={products}
            columns={columns}
            pageSize={10}
            rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
            checkboxSelection
        />
        )}

        
        
    </div>
)
```

}

UploadImages.js

```
function UploadImages({ location, match, history }) {
   const productID = match.params.id

   return (<div></div>);
};

export default UploadImages
```

Id is passed in URL

```
http://localhost:3000/images/upload/61555780c208142757be70v1
```

Answer (score 1):

i solved with `match?.params?.id`

In my case, I solved it by putting the imported params in []

```js
  const userid = match?.params?.id

  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => {
      getUser();
      return () => {
      };
    }, [userid]), // putting here 
  );
```

and thank you for answerers

Answer (score 0):

Initially when the component is loaded, `params` is not undefined.
Please do this...

```js
const productID = match && match.params && match.params.id;
```

What you are doing above is this:
You are telling `reactjs` to only assign `productID` a value after doing the sanity checks on the right-side.

**A clue into this error:**

```
Cannot read property 'params' of undefined
```

It is telling you that you are attempting to pick a `key` called `param` from an `undefined` variable (in this case `match`).

So the sanity check above means that you are telling `reactjs` to only attempt picking `param` if `match` is defined; and only attempt to pick `id` if `param` is defined.

Comment: Thank you , the error is solved but productID has value  "undefined"

Comment: Yes, because the `path` passed here `<Route path={process.env.PUBLIC_URL +"/images/upload/:id"}>` seems wrong. Try changing that to `<Route path="/images/upload/:id">`

Comment: Still its returning "undefined"

Comment: Try `console.log(match)` what does it return?

Comment: match returning undefined

Comment: You made this comment in your code `//params.id from material-ui datagrid table`... Can you add some code to that `Redirect` part? It seems the problem is there.

Comment: I added some other code in Redirect page, please check

Comment: Ok, but wait... is the your goal that when someone clicks the `Set Images` button, that it loads the `UploadImages` component?

Comment: Yes, when the Set Images button clicked i want to redirect the user to edit page with productID and there he should add images to the product and i have another page to edit other details of product in that component also match returns the value ```undefined```

Comment: But I notice the path you set up in the `<Route` is not the same as the link route for that specific button!

Comment: That i added recently to check and i forgot to remove , that's not a problem i have removed it from the code now

Comment: So `<UploadImages />` is not taking explicit props but you are destructing props when defining it... `function UploadImages({ location, match, history }) {}`. If you were using `TypeScript`, it would have complained. Try this instead, `function UploadImages(props) {}` and then do `console.log(props)` to see what kind of `props` are received by `<UploadImages />`.

Answer (score 0):

Writing `match?.params?.id` is the quickest solution

Comment: Thank you , the error is solved but it returning  "undefined" value

Comment: There is something in the code that I can't see. You're calling the component in app.js, but where do you pass the props? I'm just saying that, maybe I'm not seeing it.

Comment: i am getting match from the props and try to get id from it

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1: Using `match` prop**

```
// UploadImages.js
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

function UploadImages({ location, match, history }) {
  const productID = match.params.id;

  return (
    <div></div>
  );
}

export default UploadImages;
```

Make sure that the `UploadImages` component is rendered by a `Route` component in your application. The `match` prop is provided by the `Route` component.

**Approach 2: Using `useParams`**

```
// UploadImages.js
import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function UploadImages() {
  const {id} = useParams();

  return (
    <div></div>
  );
}

export default UploadImages;
```

In this approach, you directly use the `useParams` hook from `react-router-dom` to get the `id` parameter.